# How come my enumerated type cannot be initialized?

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Size{

     SMALL(5),MEDIUM(10),LARGE(15);

     private double value;

private Size(double value)
{
    this.value = value;
}

public double getValue()
{
    return value;
}
}


public class EnumTest
{
  Size size;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  size = Size.SMALL;

}


}
```

For some reason, I can't get my size variable to initialize to SMALL. I've seen other example where the initialization was similar to mine, but there was no syntax error in the example code I saw.

Comment: When code doesn't compile, you should include the compilation error in the question.

Comment: I was using eclipse, the error was shown before I even had a chance to compile it.

Comment: That is a compilation error. You should post the error message that appears when you hover over the red line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `EnumTest#size` field is an instance field. You cannot access it from a `static` contex, ie. your `main` method.

Either make the field `static` or create an instance of `EnumTest` and initialize it through a reference to that instance.

Comment: Which explains why the examples I saw didn't have the syntax error that I was getting. Thank you.